# mount exFAT HDD on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, mount

I'm running CentOS 7 on my server. I can't `yum install fuse-exfat exfat-utils` so I installed `exfat-utils 1.0.1-1.el7.nux` and `fuse-exfat 1.0.1-1.el7.nux` via RPM.

I have a WD Green hard disk, which is 6 TB. I formatted it exFAT on a PC (Windows) and copied some files inside. I connected it to the CentOS server via a docker and I can find it by `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 6001.2 GB, 6001175126016 bytes, 11721045168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
```

But I can't mount it by all the means I googled.

```
[root@www ~]# mount /dev/sdb /media/wd_green
mount: mount /dev/sdb on /media/wd_green failed: Function not implemented
[root@hwww ~]# mount -t exfat -o uid=plex,gid=nogroup /dev/sdb /media/wd_green
mount: failed to parse mount options
[root@www ~]# mount.exfat /dev/sdb /media/wd_green
FUSE exfat 1.0.1
ERROR: exFAT file system is not found.
```

I also tried all the commands with `sdb1`, without any good output.
What should I do to mount it? Or should I wait for some official exFAT support for CentOS 7? Any help would be appreciated!

**Update**:

```
[root@www ~]# parted /dev/sdb print
Model: JMicron Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 6001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  134MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      135MB   6001GB  6001GB               Basic data partition
```

Comment: You have to tell which partition number you want to mount. So forget about things like `mount /dev/sdb ...`. You are using GPT table, so fdisk can't display all the partitons. Can you display result of `parted /dev/sdb print` ?

Comment: @apaul thanks! I've updated my question. Sorry that it's the first time that I deal with a disk larger than 2 T and I don't know much about GPT table. Everything turns out right when I `mount /dev/sdb2 /media/wd_green`.